Allow Technicians to Create Work Orders in Field Service Mobile App
We have a Field Service Mobile App requirement wherein selected Technicians are allowed to create a Work Order (WO) via quick action.
We have successfully implemented this with an FSM Flow and a record-triggered Flow. The FSM Flow contains the necessary screens to create the WO and then when the app syncs with the server, now the related record-triggered Flow will start and consecutively creates a set of Work Order Line Items, Service Appointment (SA), an Assigned Resource record (assigned to the current user), then finally a Time Sheet Entry.
The only problem that we have is when the Technician is in an area without internet service or completely off-the-grid for hours. Since they are the one who creates the WO and SA, it must sync to the server first before they can clock in to a Time Sheet Entry. The SA record won't appear during offline mode.
The main goal for the offline capability of our implementation is for Technicians to create WO and related records then clock in and out to different Work Order Line Items within the duration of them being offline for a long time.
I have already reviewed the documentation related to Field Service Mobile. The data priming and Flow consideration topics helped me understand the mobile app further but did not explicitly states Work Order creation within the app.
Is there an alternative way to implement this offline mode approach?
